# Spotipy.User_playlist throws Error: Bad Request with more than one request

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am trying to get two of my playlists using Spotipy. I am using the spotipy.user_playlist() method. It currently works for one playlist, yet whenever I try a second one, I get an error. Both Spotify URI's are valid, and as I mentioned before, I get the first playlist perfectly fine. Here are the playlist URI's:

```
spotify:user:22tu7wr2adbylfh3n7jns7oga:playlist:7G8WJOoHzdwj81qzRDwAnO
spotify:user:22tu7wr2adbylfh3n7jns7oga:playlist:4yxnkgxG3CHayD4wACjb2y
```

I have tried creating a second authorization call with 2 different authorized apps, I have used different playlists from different users, I have also tried all the authorization methods I could find to no avail.

```py
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import spotipy.oauth2 as oauth2
cid ="****" 
secret = "****"
username = "2tu7wr2adbylfh3n7jns7oga"
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=cid, client_secret=secret) 
scope = 'user-library-read playlist-read-private'
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id=cid, client_secret=secret, redirect_uri='http://localhost/callback')
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token, client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)
if token:
    good = "4yxnkgxG3CHayD4wACjb2y"
    bad = "7G8WJOoHzdwj81qzRDwAnO"
    good_playlist = sp.user_playlist(username, playlist_id=good)
    bad_playlist = sp.user_playlist(username, playlist_id=bad)
else:
    print("Can't get token for", username)
```

This produces the error:

```py
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/client.py in _internal_call(self, method, url, payload, params)
    118         try:
--> 119             r.raise_for_status()
    120         except:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py in raise_for_status(self)
    939         if http_error_msg:
--> 940             raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
    941 

HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/2tu7wr2adbylfh3n7jns7oga/playlists/7G8WJOoHzdwj81qzRDwAnO

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SpotifyException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-b0cbbe8e4d4f> in <module>
     10     bad = "7G8WJOoHzdwj81qzRDwAnO"
     11     good_playlist = sp.user_playlist(username, playlist_id=good)
---> 12     bad_playlist = sp.user_playlist(username, playlist_id=bad)
     13 else:
     14     print("Can't get token for", username)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/client.py in user_playlist(self, user, playlist_id, fields)
    376             return self._get("users/%s/starred" % (user), fields=fields)
    377         plid = self._get_id('playlist', playlist_id)
--> 378         return self._get("users/%s/playlists/%s" % (user, plid), fields=fields)
    379 
    380     def user_playlist_tracks(self, user, playlist_id=None, fields=None,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/client.py in _get(self, url, args, payload, **kwargs)
    144         while retries > 0:
    145             try:
--> 146                 return self._internal_call('GET', url, payload, kwargs)
    147             except SpotifyException as e:
    148                 retries -= 1

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/client.py in _internal_call(self, method, url, payload, params)
    122                 raise SpotifyException(r.status_code,
    123                     -1, '%s:\n %s' % (r.url, r.json()['error']['message']),
--> 124                     headers=r.headers)
    125             else:
    126                 raise SpotifyException(r.status_code,

SpotifyException: http status: 400, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/2tu7wr2adbylfh3n7jns7oga/playlists/7G8WJOoHzdwj81qzRDwAnO:
 Bad request
```

When I go to the link, it says:

```
{
  "error": {
    "status": 401,
    "message": "No token provided"
  }
}
```

Yet, I have a token from the authorization. I am very confused. If this is a duplicate post please let me know, I couldn't find the solution anywhere else.

Edit: I used the function `python sp.user_playlist_tracks()` instead, and now it works for both playlists.

Comment: Please consider [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56156959/edit) to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). Currently, we can't reproduce your issue because we don't have code which will run and produce the error you've shown.

Comment: I put in the authorization call and the playlist call, what more is necessary?

Comment: have you tried running these suggested functions from the spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth module? ```get_access_token(code)```, ```get_authorize_url(state=None, show_dialog=False)```,```is_token_expired(token_info)```

Comment: Will try this out, thank you.

Comment: So I've noticed that no matter what ```python good_playlist = sp.user_playlist(username, playlist_id=good)``` always works and ```python bad_playlist = sp.user_playlist(username, playlist_id=bad) ``` never works, I'm at a loss here.

Comment: You could try swapping the order of the calls to see if that makes a difference

Comment: Also you don't need to provide both `auth` and `client_credentials_manager` to the `Spotify` class, one of these will suffice. It's defaulting to just use your `auth` at the moment.

Comment: I fixed it sort of, I used a normal auth and instead of calling ```python sp.user_playlist()```, called ```python sp.user_playlist_tracks()```